# Not able to use .htaccess in Ubuntu 10.0.4

Tags: .htaccess

I have AllowOverride All in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.

I added .htaccess with the following code.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Without this htaccess, I am able to see the web page. but after adding this I am not able to see it. I get the following error.

Could anyone tell me how to fix the problem?

Thanks in advance.

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal
>   error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server
>   administrator, webmaster@localhost and
>   inform them of the time the error
>   occurred, and anything you might have
>   done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may
>   be available in the server error log.
>   Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) Server at
>   localhost Port 80

Comment: Is the mod_rewrite module loaded? Do you have a /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load symlink?

Comment: Did you look in the error log?

Answer (score 0):

What's $1 in the REQUEST_COND? Shouldn't it be REQUEST_FILENAME?

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $REQUEST_FILENAME !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]`